# Opening serial port connection issue - can't find port path (windows)

Tags: python, windows, mingw, port, pyserial

I'm trying to communicate with my 3D printer via serial (putty) and I'm getting the following errors:

```
File "C:\kivygui\MainMenu.py", line 44, in <module>
 ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200)  # open serial port
File "C:\kivygui\virt\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 33, in __init__
  super(Serial, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\kivygui\virt\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 244, in __init__
  self.open()
File "C:\kivygui\virt\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 64, in open
  raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
 serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port '/dev/ttyACM0': 
    FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system can not find the path specified.', None, 3)
```

Command I'm passing:

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200)  # open serial port
```

Putty settings:

```
http://prntscr.com/xzjmcx
http://prntscr.com/xzjmxm
```

I'm using sublinetxt as my editor and mingw64 as my compiler.

Comment: which os are you using?

Comment: cause it looks like you are using either Linux or mac but it is tagged windows

Comment: I had it running on raspberry pi, tried switching to windows as i wont have access to the pi for a few days

Answer (score 0):

windows and linux have different ways of handling usb devices, assuming it is looking for a com port, you'd need to open up device manager and look for 'Ports'- see image, I have an arduino plugged in, and it's on COM3, therefore in order to open it with pyserial I would use the following:

```
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200)
```

you may also need to change the BaudRate (the 115200) if you are not sure what value it should be, common baudrates are: 9600, 14400, 19200, 38400, 57600, 115200, 128000 and 256000

[image]

Comment: Hi, I've changed mine to com4 and still getting the same error. I think the baudrate is fine because it does connect to the printer on the putty. Check out these screenshots: http://prntscr.com/y07jco http://prntscr.com/y07kay

Comment: when it raises access denied that usually means it is in use - possibly by putty at that time, close putty, you may need to unplug and plug back in the USB or even power cycle the printer

Comment: how'd it go? :)

Comment: I was using com3 twice that's why it wouldnt let me use it i had it open in putty then i was trying to open it in mingw thats where i was going wrong